# How to send specifically an IMAGE file from client to server using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, server

So I want to send and IMAGE file from client to server using Python Paramiko. For example: .jpeg, .jpg, .png

I don't get an error, but, it does print this message:

```
Failure
```

Here is example code:

```py
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    import paramiko

    class Client:
        def __init__(self, hostname, username, password):
            self.hostname = hostname
            self.username = username
            self.password = password
            self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()

        def connect(self):
            self.client.load_system_host_keys()
            self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.client.connect(hostname=self.hostname, username=self.username, password=self.password, port=22)
        
        def close(self):
            self.client.close()

    ImageGrab.grab().save("screenshot.png") # Saves a screenshot
    client = Client("hostname", "username", "password")
    client.connect()
    sftp_client = client.client.open_sftp()
    sftp_client.put("screenshot.png", "/home") # Line that has the error
```

The line that I believe is messed up is the last line.

Feel free to run this code and test it. If you have any questions about this, go ahead and ask. If I did not include enough information, please say something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1000) post on paramiko github repo, you need to specify the destination parameter to the file name instead of the directory name, such as

`sftp_client.put("screenshot.png", "/home/screenshot.png")`